# Modifying an existing document using pdfstamper

Tags: java, itext, pdfstamper

I have a pdf which is half static and half dynamic which can grow multiple pages. I created the static part in Adobe LiveCycle and using itext to create the dynamic part. The dynamic part of the form is a table which has to expand based on the input across multiple pages. The form has acrofields in both the parts.

I have used columntext and pdfstamper to add the content to the existing pdf and the table grows dynamically which is working fine. The problems are

1. In every table cell, an acrofield needs to get added. I used pdfcell event to create it but after some googling, I could only find code using pdfwriter but not using pdf stamper.
2. on the first page, how to restrict the table content so that it doesn't go till the end of the page and I can insert page numbers at the bottom ?
3. I need to add a signature field  at the end of the table. how do I know the coordinates of the end of the dynamic table?

My code snippet for dynamic table part:

```
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(1));
Rectangle rectPage1 = new Rectangle(792, 270);
column.setSimpleColumn(rectPage1);
column.addElement(table);
int pagecount = 1;
Rectangle rectPage2 = new Rectangle(792, 540);
int status = column.go();
while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(status) ) {
status = triggerNewPage(stamper, pagesize, column, rectPage2,   ++pagecount);
}

public int triggerNewPage(PdfStamper stamper, Rectangle pagesize, ColumnText column, Rectangle rect, int pagecount) throws DocumentException {
stamper.insertPage(pagecount, pagesize);
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(pagecount);
column.setCanvas(canvas);
column.setSimpleColumn(rect);
return column.go();
}
```

Comment: Does the table start on a separate page? In that case you might want to consider creating the table in a new Document using the `PdfWriter` techniques you found and then combining the static part with this table part using `PdfCopy`.

Comment: The question is confusing because you seem to want a dynamic table (which makes me assume that you want XFA forms) and you're using Adobe LiveCycle (which makes me assume that you're creating XFA forms), but then you say you're creating *the static part* (which makes me assume you're not creating an XFA form) and you talk about AcroForm fields (which aren't dynamic). The fact that you mix those things make it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: The table starts on the same page. 
@BrunoLowagie I don't want to use XFA forms. I just used LiveCycle because I am a LiveCycle developer and new to itext :) . I referred static part as I the one which position is constant and doesn't expand dynamically There are Acro fields both in the static part and in the table I inserted using itext. I hope I am clear.
Also, u mentioned tht Acrofields are not dynamic, Does that mean If I insert Acrofields using itext, they cannot expand based on the size of the cell ?

Comment: AcroForm fields are not dynamic in the sense that they are defined using widget annotations. The annotation dictionary of a widget annotation contains a `/Rect` entry that defines the exact coordinates of a rectangle. That rectangle is fixed and can not expand based on the content you're adding. Read ISO-32000-1 (aka the PDF specification) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I will just add the text to the pdf cell without creating Acrofield. Now the 2nd and 3rd part of my question.

I want to insert a margin at the bottom of each page with page numbers and I am not sure how to control the dynamic table. Also, need to know the coordinates where the table ends so that i create a signature field. I am editing the question to add my code snippet

Comment: @BrunoLowagie To add the margin to the existing pdf, Should I use pdfwriter instead of pdfstamper as I did in my code so that I can get the exact coordinates of the text?

Comment: When manipulating an existing PDF, `PdfStamper` is the class you need. I don't see a scenario where you'd use `PdfWriter`. Then again: it isn't clear what you're trying to do. Maybe your question is similar to [How to extend the page size of a PDF to add a watermark?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-extend-page-size-pdf-add-watermark)